# Expression of a ring $R$ as product of two rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be commutative ring with unity. An element $e$ is called an idempotent if $e^2=e$. Show that if $R$ has an idempotent different from $0$ and $1$ then $R$ can be written as product of two non-zero rings.
Please help me. If anyone can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that $1-e \neq 0,1$ is also an idempotent. What is $e(1-e)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$eR$ is a ring with identity $e$ and $(1-e)R$ is a ring with identity $(1-e)$. They're both contained in $R$, and they are your candidates.

Work to show their sum is equal to $R$ and is a direct sum.